# Find Successor and Predecessor using a modification to AVL tree in O(1)

Tags: time-complexity, avl-tree, operation

So I got this task to suggest a AVL tree with the capability of performing the fallowing two operations in O(1):

Successor takes (1) - return the successor.
Predecessor takes (1)- return the Predecessor

I am kind of stuck after trying to think of a solution for this.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not so much about modifying the tree or implementing any complicated predecessor/successor-finding logic to be able to physically traverse the tree to find successor/predecessor nodes in constant time as much as simply adding succ and pred links to every node in the tree, using them in your `predecessor(n)` and `successor(n)` functions, and maintaining these links over insert and delete operations.

All you have to be careful about with this approach to ensure `successor(n)` and `predecessor(n)` are  actually O(1) is that the time complexity of maintaining succ/pred links does not exceed the complexity of the operations which require link updates. For example, because inserting a new node into a balanced tree is an O(lg n) operation, updating successor/predecessor links after insert cannot exceed O(lg n) (as otherwise your subsequent lookups would technically be doing amortized work greater than O(1)).

The steps you have to take on each insert and delete operation to maintain pred and succ links are actually pretty simple, and thankfully the complexities introduced to the AVL tree by the re-balance operation don't really affect them because while re-balance changes the structure of the tree, it doesn't affect the tree's ordering and therefore doesn't affect predecessor/successor relations.

Finding the successor and predecessor of a given node in balanced BST (which an AVL tree is guaranteed to be) is O(lg n), and don't differ in terms of logic from the operations you would perform to find predecessor and successor in a regular BST. Therefore, after inserting a new node n into your AVL, simply find n's successor and predecessor nodes and update the appropriate links:

```
insert(n) {
  ...
  # normal AVL insert and rebalance logic
  ...
  predecessor, successor = findPredAndSucc(n)
  if (predecessor) predecessor.succ = n
  if (successor)   successor.pred = n
  n.pred = predecessor
  n.succ = successor
}
```

When deleting n, you'll also have to find n's predecessor and successor and update links as in:

```
delete(n) {
  # save these values first so they aren't lost when n is deleted
  predecessor, successor = findPredAndSucc(n) 
  ...
  # normal AVL delete and rebalance logic
  ...
  if (predecessor) predecessor.succ = successor
  if (successor)   successor.pred = predecessor
}
```

I'm slightly conflating the node n and the value of n (if inserting/deleting by value you would have to traverse the tree to find n first), but you get the idea.

Following this approach, after every insert and delete each node will have direct links to its predecessor/successor nodes, and because of the AVL-tree's self balancing property the time spent finding the relevant nodes to update these links on after inserts and deletes doesn't add any additional complexity to those operations (finding predecessor and successor nodes don't require more than 2 O(h) = O(lg n) traversals each, the same complexity as insert and delete themselves, therefore not changing the overall complexity), so our `successor(n)` and `predecessor(n)` functions will be overall O(1) if they just follow the succ and pred links we set.